# Find equation of envelope of a family of Arrhenius-like exponential curves

Tags: geometry, derivatives, exponential-function, envelope

I have an equation for an Arrhenius-like exponential curve:

$y = t\exp(-1000t/x)$

Where t is some scaling parameter. If I allow $t$ to vary from 1 to 20 in steps of 0.1, I obtain the family of curves given in the image.

[image]
The black dots in the image indicate intersection points between two neighbouring curves. I would now like to find a mathematical form of the envelope of this set of curves, but I don't really know what to do once I have the equation in the form $f(t,x,y) = 0$. How can this be calculated?

Edit: Image has been adjusted to better represent the given equation, all extra constants that were originally included have been set to unity.

Comment: Are you sure you plotted the equation in the text of your question? For very low, positive $x$, and for a positive $t$, the exponential goes to $0$

Comment: @Andrei In fact, the confusion comes from the logarithmic scale on the ordinate axis.

Comment: @JeanMarie for positive $t$ and $x$, $y$ must be less than $t$. Where are the $10^4-10^5$ values coming from?

Comment: Andrei: Indeed, you are right, the OP must have forgotten to indicate a multiplication by a big constant...

Comment: Differentiate the equation wrt $t$ and eliminate $t$ between the two equations.

Comment: I have adjusted the original plot to better reflect the equation. The original issues emerged from fitting parameters which has very large values in the original plot

Comment: If I take log base-10 of both sides to reproduce the log plot, I get $\displaystyle \log_{10}y=\frac{\ln y}{\ln 10}=\frac{\ln t-1000t/x}{\ln 10}$. But plotting this function doesn't produce an envelope.

Comment: @Semiclassical Furthermore for value say $x=1$, and for any value of $t \ge 1$ the numerator is negative, while we see the curves situated in the first quadrant... ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Standard procedure C discriminant.  Partially differentiate wrt $t$ and eliminate $t.$

Let a = -1000;

$$ e^{y/t} = \frac{at}{x}, \quad e^{y/t} \cdot \frac{-y}{t^2}=\frac{a}{x} \tag1 $$

Eliminate $e^{y/t} $ and cancell $\dfrac{a}{x}$

$$\to y=-t;\quad e^{-1}= \frac{-ay}{x} \tag 2 $$

$$\to \left(  \frac{y}{x}= \frac{-1}{ae }\right)\tag 3 $$

Comment: On the given graphics, I don't see any straght line...

Comment: Thanks I was nt too sure, shall delete; only a part straight line seen between $ 10^0, 10^{-1}$ in given graphic.

Comment: In an Arrhenius plot, where you plot log(y) against 1/x, a straight line only appears for an exponential function, the given solution would look like a curve on said plot, consistent with the graphic

Comment: To the OP, about the c-discriminant (which isn't part of classical syllabi, at least under this name) see [here](https://solitaryroad.com/c652.html#:~:text=the%20c-discriminantis%20the%20result%20of%20eliminating%20c%20between,a%20cusp%20locus%2C%20a%20tac-locus%2C%20or%20a%20particular)